# putting the whole code together like JQuery

Tags: javascript, optimization

I know the question sounds weird but how can i put my code together? Its there any tool that help me out with this?

Example:

```
var d = "Hello world";
if(typeof d == 'string')
{
 console.log("its a string!");
}else{
console.log("it isnt a string!");
}
```

to

```
if(typeof d == 'string'){console.log("its a string!");}else{console.log("it isnt a tring!");}
```

I have a alot of code and i read once that puttin all your code like this would run faster and he mentioned some tools but i dont remember its names and the post neither.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a **javascript minifier**.  Removing whitespace from a page's markup or output causes it to be transmitted to the browser more quickly, not necessarily run faster.

[JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as *minification*.  There are a ton of minifying tools all over the place (just Google "JavaScript minifier.")  Some you can run online.  Others are built into frameworks like Ruby On Rails' `uglifier`.  There are also some CDNs (such as CloudFlare) that will minify JS from your site for you as it is served.

Minification cuts down on file size .. sometimes significantly.  All those whitespace characters add up.  This makes the JS file faster to download, which can be very nice for people with slow connections -- especially on mobile devices.

Once it has been downloaded, minified JS probably won't run any faster than unminified.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the naming convention for minified files is `.min.js`. For example if your development code is named `myscript.js`, then the minified version would be `myscript.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in learning how jQuery does it, they actually have their build file on their git hub page. They use a tool called [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) to concat, lint, minify and test their script before it is shipped. It is a relatively simple tool to use, and it is extremely powerful. You can [view jquery's "GruntFile" here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)